# Embed private/closed facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if it´s possible to embed a private/closed facebook group?

Are there perhaps any features in the graph api that can help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to access a private group is to use the `user_managed_groups` permission and get the feed with the `/group-id/feed` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/feed

Of course this only works with an admin account. You should not put the feed of a private group online anyway, that would make the whole point of a group being private useless.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not planning to put it online, but on another closed environment. It looks like I have to create my own feed by using the api then..